# Filter multiple arrays with $redact

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I m actually trying to make a mongodb request that fill filters first on a list and then on another list.

**Explanations**

I have the following objects in my database :

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "title": "MySuperProject",
  "files": [
    {
      "title":"My skiing day !",
      "right":[{
        "role":"USER",
        "access":["read"]
      }]
    },
    {
      "title":"My little dog, so cute !",
      "right":[{
        "role":"OTHER",
        "access":["read"]
      }]
    }
  ],

"people": [
    {
      "userName":"borat",
      "role":"OTHERONE",
      "right":[{
        "role":"USER",
        "access":["read"]
      }]
    },
    {
      "userName":"Thomas",
      "role":"OTHER",
      "right":[{
        "role":"OTHER",
        "access":["read"]
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I need**

I need to pass a parameter to my function that is the current user role. In my case I pass the "USER" role.

This way, I need to retrieve this result :

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "title": "MySuperProject",
  "files": [
    {
      "title":"My skiing day !",
      "right":[{
        "role":"USER",
        "access":["read"]
      }]
    }
  ],

"people": [
    {
      "userName":"borat",
      "role":"OTHER",
      "right":[{
        "role":"USER",
        "access":["read"]
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

That reduces both list on the item role that matches mine.

**What I have**

I have a query that reduces the list of files by the "role" attribute.

The fact is that in my people list, I have two time the role attribute :

- One time to determine the people role
- One time to detemine which kind of people can access (right access) the people profile

And my query reduces the people resultset by matching the first role met (the people.role instead of the people.right.role).

My query is the following :

```
db.t.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "title": projectTitle
    }
  },
  {
    $redact: {
      $cond: [{
        $eq: [role, {
          $ifNull: ["$role", role]
        }]
      }, "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE"]
    }
  },
  {
    $redact: {
      $cond: [{
        $gt: [{
          $size: {
            $ifNull: ["$right", [1]]
          }
        }, 0]
      }, "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE"]
    }
  },
])
```

Sum up : I need that the query reduces the people AND the file list matching both right.role values

Answer (score 0):

The [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline stage is not the best tool for this as it does not translate well to *"different conditions at different levels"* nor *"treating differnt arrays differently"* by the nature of it's intended function.

The better cases here are plain old array filtering, for which there have been methods around for some time.

The best option is [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) from MongoDB 3.2 if you have that:

```js
db.t.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "title": 1,
        "files": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$files",
                "as": "file",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$file.right.role", "USER" ] }
            }
        },
        "people": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$people",
                "as": "person",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$person.right.role", "USER" ] }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

For MongoDB 2.6, and if your array elements are truly "distinct" and no two are the same within a document, then you can "emulate" that newer function using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to remove any `false` results from the array:

```js
db.t.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "title": 1,
        "files": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$files",
                    "as": "file",
                    "in": {
                       "$cond": [
                           { "$eq": [ "$$file.right.role", "USER" ] },
                           "$$file",
                           false
                       ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        },
        "people": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$people",
                    "as": "person",
                    "in": {
                       "$cond": [
                           { "$eq": [ "$$person.right.role", "USER" ] },
                           "$$person",
                           false
                       ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

It's the same basic conditional test, except in the latter case `$map` just returns an element per array element provided as input. So either the matched element or a value of `false`, which would then be removed by the "set comparison" to `false` from `$setDifference`.

These are both single pipeline stage operations, so they are the fastest ways to do this.

As always, unless you really need this information to carry forward into further aggregation pipeline stages, or if indeed you reduce the content from the arrays by a "significant" amount that saves you considerable network traffic, then it will always be better to do this "filtration" in the client to the database itself.

Neither of these processes would really have much overhead, but the client code is arguably just as straight-forward, and what might be gained from a "little" less network traffic is probably lost in the cost of processing on the server.